# Sample exactly four maintaining almost equal sample distances

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to generate appointment times for yearly scheduled visits. The available `days=1:365` and the first appointment should be randomly chosen `first=sample(days,1,replace=F)`

Now given the first appointment I want to generate 3 more appointment in the space between `1:365` so that there will be exactly 4 appointments in the 1:365 space, and as equally spaced between them as possible.

I have tried

```
point<-sort(c(first-1:5*364/4,first+1:5*364/4 ));point<-point[point>0 & point<365]
```

but it does not always give me 4 appointments. I have eventually run this many times and picked only the samples with 4 appointments, but I wanted to ask if there is a more elegant way to get exactly 4 points as equally distanced a s possible.

Comment: Can you add an example? It isn't immediately clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking of equal spacing (around 91 days between appointments) in a year starting at the first appointment...  Essentially one appointment per quarter of the year.

```
# Find how many days in a quarter of the year
quarter = floor(365/4)
first = sample(days, 1)
all = c(first, first + (1:3)*quarter)
all[all > 365] = all[all > 365] - 365
all
sort(all)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible  example ONLY - you need to take this out.
first <- sample(1:365,1)
points <- c(first+(0:3)*(365-first)/4)
points
# [1]  97 164 231 298
```

Another way uses

```
points <- c(first+(0:3)*(365-first)/3)
```

This creates 4 points euqally spaced on `[first, 365]`, but the last point will always be 365.

The reason your code is giving unexpected results is because you use `first-1:5*364/4`. This creates points prior to first, some of which can be < 0. Then you exclude those with `points[points>0...]`.